# RazorPay Integration with Expo Go

Tags: react-native, expo, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am building a project with expo go, now i need to add in-App purchases And after a lot of research, i got to know that RazorPay is now supporting Expo. Till now i am testing my project in expo app in my ios phone and android phone separately and all screens are running error free in my both devices.

what i need to know:

1. How to integrate RazorPay for my expo go app?
2. Can i write a single code for payments that works for both android and ios?
3. Can I test that payments code In expo app like before without making any eas builds?

for Q3 if not possible then we need to maintain 2 projects for android and ios separately?

Note:- If there are any better gateways other than RazorPay which make my task easy then please suggest them (that gateway should support INR currency).